# About the properties of the coresets in k-median clustering

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms

I have seen two observations from the paper by Har-Peled but I do not know how to prove them
(i) If $C1$ and $C2$ are the $(k, ε)$-coresets for disjoint sets P1 and P2 respectively, then $C1 ∪ C2$ is a $(k, ε)$-coreset for $P1 ∪ P2$.
(ii) If $C1$ is $(k, ε)$-coreset for $C2$, and $C2$ is a$(k, δ)$-coreset for $C3$, then $C1$ is a $(k, ε+δ)$- coreset for $C3$

Can anyone please figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The k-medians clustering objective is defined here as

```
sum_{p in points} weight(p) distance(p, centers)
```

where `centers` is the set of `k` centers and `distance(p, centers)` is the distance to the closest center.

The first observation amounts to observing that the objective function is additive. Letting `(C1, w1)` and `(C2, w2)` be the core-sets, we consider the core-set `(C1 union C2, w1 union w2)`, which satisfies

```
sum_{p in C1 union C2} (w1 union w2)(p) distance(p, centers)
= sum_{p in C1} w1(p) distance(p, centers) + sum_{p in C2} w2(p) distance(p, centers)
<= exp(eps) sum_{p in P1} weight(p) distance(p, centers) + exp(eps) sum_{p in P2} weight(p) distance(p, centers)
= exp(eps) (sum_{p in P1 union P2} weight(p) distance(p, centers))
```

and similarly for the lower bound.

As for the second observation,

```
sum_{p in C1} w1(p) distance(p, centers)
<= exp(eps) sum_{p in C2} w2(p) distance(p, centers)
<= exp(eps) exp(delta) sum_{p in C3} w3(p) distance(p, centers)
= exp(eps + delta) sum_{p in C3} w3(p) distance(p, centers),
```

and similarly for the lower bound.

Comment: But the error is multiplicative $(1+- \epsilon)$ not $e^\epsilon$

Answer (score 0):

Proof of claim 1:

For every query q of k points we have:

$Cost(C1\bigcup C2,q)=Cost(C1,q)+Cost(C2,q)\\
\leq (1+\epsilon)\cdot Cost(P1,q)+(1+\epsilon)\cdot Cost(P2,q)=(1+\epsilon)Cost(P1\bigcup P2,q)$

And a similar proof can be made for the lower bound.

Claim 2 is only approximately correct for small values of $\epsilon,\delta$.

Proof of claim 2:

$Cost(C1,q)\leq (1+\epsilon)Cost(C2,q)\leq (1+\epsilon)(1+\delta)Cost(C3,q)=\\(1+\epsilon+\delta+\epsilon\cdot\delta)Cost(C3,q)\approx (1+\epsilon+\delta)Cost(C3,q)$

And a similar proof can be made for the lower bound.